# Can you use "se tromper" to check to see if you have reached the right person when you call or email someone for the first time?

Tags: usage

> J’espère ne pas m’être trompé de **Docteur XXX**.

I'm about to send a business-related email to someone for the first time, and at the beginning of a message, I want to include a sentence to check to see if I have reached the right person.

Normally, you'd place a noun such as "numéro":

> J’espère ne pas m’être trompé de **numéro**.

... but is it acceptable to put a person's name there instead?

Answer (score 2):

You are right to wonder if your first sentence is correct because it is not. I don’t have the exact grammar explanation, but you cannot name someone after using "de...". However you could just say

> J’espère ne pas m’être trompé de docteur.

In this case, if you want to call the person by his name I suppose it will have been dealt with beforehand, like in the introduction? ("Cher Docteur XXX,...)

Edit: I am assuming here that XXX is the person’s name. After a second thought I find the question a bit strange because I think in English you wouldn’t say something like « I hope I didn’t reach the wrong Dr. Smith »?

Comment: "J’espère ne pas m’être trompé de Docteur XXX" Hi. I wonder if this sentence can be interpreted instead as "I hope I didn't misjudge Doctor XXX's **character** (or whatever)"?

Comment: By the way, in English you'd say something like: "I hope I'm not mistaken in assuming that ..."

Comment: I get your 2nd comment, which could be translated as ”J’espère ne pas me tromper en considérant que... [vous êtes le Docteur XXX].”. However I am a bit troubled by your first comment. What do you mean by ”misjudging someone’s character”?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to consider you first sentence as incorrect.

You can indeed write that when you believe there is a possibility for several doctors to share the same name and prepare the recipient for a possible mistake.

I haven't found occurrences of *trompé de docteur XXX* but here are some similar constructions:

> - Toutes mes excuses pour ma réponse, mais si je me suis trompé de Robert, ma sympathie à ton attention est identique.
> - — Ah bon ? Je me suis trompé de Julie. Ce n'est pas le numéro de ma fille ?
> - Avant son spectacle, Jamel Debbouze s'est trompé... de Vernouillet
> - Désolé. Je me suis trompé de M. Pickford.